# Jenkins: "Windows PowerShell" не понимает переменные заданные в "Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild"

Tags: powershell, jenkins, msbuild

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать? - чтобы подружить шаг сборки "Windows PowerShell"   с "Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild" в jenkins

Описание: 
1. В  "Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild"  используется путь для сохранения wsp пакета:  /p:BasePackagePath=C:\Jenkins\Deployment\Name\%BUILD_DATE%\${GIT_COMMIT}\%BUILD_NUMBER%\

2. Для обновления пакета используется powershell скрипт, для этого в шаге "Windows PowerShel"  прописан путь до сохраненного файла:
   cd C:\Jenkins\Deployment_Updater
   C:\Jenkins\Deployment_Updater\NoStopUpdate_v1.ps1 -p1 \server_name\C$\Jenkins\Deployment\Name\%BUILD_DATE%\${GIT_COMMIT}\%BUILD_NUMBER%\

Проблема:
Когда процесс сборки в Jenkins доходит до попытки использования wsp пакета, попытка проваливается, т.к. шаг сборки "Windows PowerShel" не видит полный путь (по логу не видит - ${GIT_COMMIT}):
[OrgDocs] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins4836002707464403717.ps1'"
Update Test Stand
Path to wsp: \server_name\C$\Jenkins\Deployment\Name\%BUILD_DATE%\%BUILD_NUMBER%\
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\server_name\C$\Jenkins\Deployment\Name\%BUILD_DATE%\%BUILD_NUMBER%\' because it does not exist.

Если прописать, например:

cd C:\Jenkins\Deployment_Updater
C:\Jenkins\Deployment_Updater\NoStopUpdate_v1.ps1 -p1 \server_name\C$\Jenkins\Deployment\Name\wspfolder

то  jenkins проглатывает путь и wsp  пакеты устанавливаются на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:
В "Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild" прописал путь к сохранению файла p:BasePackagePath=C:\Jenkins\Deployment\Name\%BUILD_DATE%\%GIT_COMMIT%\%BUILD_NUMBER%\

а в "Windows PowerShell":
cd C:\Jenkins\Deployment_Updater C:\Jenkins\Deployment_Updater\NoStopUpdate_v1.ps1 -p1 \server_name\C$\Jenkins\Deployment\Name\${env:BUILD_DATE}\${env:GIT_COMMIT}\${env:BUILD_NUMBER}\